# Crash when using ViewModel with a repository for a Room Database

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am currently trying to setup a Room Database for my application. I managed to setup the room itself, following the [Room database tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-persisting-data-room?hl=fr&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-6-pathway-2%3Fhl%3Dfr%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-persisting-data-room#8), but when trying to use the ViewModel I have created, the application instantly crashes when the activity using it starts.

**Here is my ViewModel for the activity :**

```
package com.example.projetdevmob.ProjetUI

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.projetdevmob.Data.Player
import com.example.projetdevmob.Data.PlayerRepository

class SignupViewModel(private val playerRepository: PlayerRepository) : ViewModel() {

    var playerUiState by mutableStateOf(PlayerUiState())
    
    fun updateUiState(playerDetails: PlayerDetails) {
        playerUiState =
            PlayerUiState(playerDetails = playerDetails, isEntryValid = validateInput(playerDetails))
    }
    
    private fun validateInput(uiState: PlayerDetails = PlayerUiState().playerDetails): Boolean {
        return with(uiState) {
            name.isNotBlank() && password.isNotBlank()
        }
    }
    
    suspend fun savePlayer() {
        if (validateInput()) {
            playerRepository.insert(PlayerUiState().playerDetails.toPlayer())
        }
    }
    
    init {
        playerUiState = PlayerUiState()
    }

}

data class PlayerUiState(
val playerDetails: PlayerDetails = PlayerDetails(),
val isEntryValid: Boolean = false
)

data class PlayerDetails(
val uid: Int = 0,
val name: String = "",
val password: String = "",
val limcoins: Long = 0,
)

fun PlayerDetails.toPlayer(): Player = Player(
uid = uid,
playerName = name,
playerPassword = password,
playerLimcoins = limcoins
)

fun Player.toPlayerUiState(isEntryValid: Boolean = false): PlayerUiState = PlayerUiState(
playerDetails = this.toPlayerDetails(),
isEntryValid = isEntryValid
)

fun Player.toPlayerDetails(): PlayerDetails = PlayerDetails(
uid = uid,
name = playerName,
password = playerPassword,
limcoins = playerLimcoins
)
```

**At first I didn't have a factory for my viewModel, so I created one, following the same model as in the tutorial :**

```
package com.example.projetdevmob.ProjetUI

import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.initializer
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.viewModelFactory

object AppViewModelProvider {
val Factory = viewModelFactory {
initializer {
SignupViewModel(gameApplication().container.playerRepository)
}
}
}

fun CreationExtras.gameApplication(): GameApplication =
(this\[ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY\] as GameApplication)
```

**And finally, I created an Application class :**

```
package com.example.projetdevmob.ProjetUI

import android.app.Application
import com.example.projetdevmob.Data.AppContainer
import com.example.projetdevmob.Data.AppDataContainer

class GameApplication : Application() {

    lateinit var container: AppContainer
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        container = AppDataContainer(this)
    }

}
```

**the manifest.xml :**

```
<application
            android:name=".ProjetUI.GameApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjetDevMob"
            tools:targetApi="31"\>

        //Activites

</application
```

**Here's my activity :**

```
package com.example.projetdevmob.ProjetUI

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import com.example.projetdevmob.R
import com.example.projetdevmob.ui.theme.ProjetDevMobTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class Signup : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val signupViewModel by viewModels<SignupViewModel> {
            AppViewModelProvider.Factory
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ProjetDevMobTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    signup(signupViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun signup(
    viewModel: SignupViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
// Displaying the screen 
}
```

I have tried some ways to use the ViewModel inside my composable function, such as the one just up there, but also :

```
@Composable
fun signup(
    viewModel: SignupViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory),
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
)
```

Why does it keep crashing ? I have tried starting the activity without the viewModel and it works just fine. What should I modify to make it work ? Thank you.

Comment: show your log and exception stacktrace

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.projetdevmob.GameApplication
at com.example.projetdevmob.ProjetUI.AppViewModelProviderKt.gameApplication(AppViewModelProvider.kt:19) ... 

Is this what you asked for ?

Comment: yep. your `gameApplication()` method seems invalid, but you haven't posted real code and hard to guess what you are trying to treat `as GameApplication`. for shure nothing proper